# Set MKMapView Span without moving map

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit

How do you adjust the `MKMapView` span (zoom) without moving the map location. I am trying to do this in an attempt to limit the user from zooming out further than preferable.

Comment: can you give me any feedback of my answer, did you tried?, is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Use **MKCoordinateSpanMake()** method, for an instance

let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)

Comment: How do I then apply that to the map view?

Comment: Sorry for the format, create latitude and longitude values let latitude = "value" let longitude ="value"  then setup span let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), span: span)
        
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

Comment: can you expand on that? I am putting the application of the fixed span in the `regionWillChangeAnimated` method. @Sujanth

Comment: using `mapView.setRegion(...)` pans the pan to the region given. I do not want to programatically pan the map - only fix the zoom. @sujanth

Answer (score 1):

Try making the zoom with the `MKMapView` camera instead, adjusting `eyeAltitude` parameter can help you

```
func makeZoomWithCamera(){
    let newCamera: MKMapCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: self.mapView.camera.centerCoordinate, fromEyeCoordinate: self.mapView.camera.centerCoordinate, eyeAltitude: 10)
    self.mapView.setCamera(newCamera, animated: true)
}
```